# Modelling a school timetable database

Tags: database-design

I'm working on a design for a database for school timetable and I need some help. So, basically, the database is made up of tables like teacher, student, subject, TimePeriod, and Classroom.

I would just like some advice to see if what I'm doing is allowed. It might not necessarily be good, but I'm beyond that.

I’ve created a many-to-many relationship between subject and timePeriod so essentially I'm saying that many Subjects are allocated to many timePeriods, and I've created an "association" table called SubjectPeriod between these. I've then linked two other tables to the SubjectPeriod table like below:

```
SubjectPeriod (TimePeriodID, SubjectD, ClassroomID, TeacherID, Details)
```

Classroom and Teacher are connected to SubjectPeriod as a one-to-many as in:

- One teacher teaches many SubjectPeriods
- And One Classroom hosts Many SubjectPeriods

Does this make sense or is it even allowed?

I'm not too confident with database design so I'm struggling a little with this.

Comment: It's allowed and, on the surface, it seems to make sense. Although, I haven't examined it closely for more specific issues...

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Yea it makes sense logically at least as you say on the surface seems fine. Im a bit worried though, the values will look something like this.

(1,4,5,223, 1001, ‘Joe Bloggs Science class in room 223’)

My main issue then seems to be with Participation, I will probably have to allow nulls for Teacher and Classroom if I don’t want records to delete when Teachers or Rooms are changed around.
Of course that has me more confused. TimePeriod, subject, classroom, and teacher could all potentially change in such a table

Comment: There are many ways you could organize your data that would work. Broadly speaking, you want to think about efficiency and robustness. Efficiency in the sense that you need to think about the most common kinds of access you need, and structure your data such that you can make those accesses with as simple a query as possible. Robustness in that you want to avoid data redundancy that you have to enforce (same information kept in two different tables). The specifics of these depends upon your application.

Comment: I would create a one-to-one subject -> room_period and one-to-many room -> period, which prevents double booking (which your design does not) and this is how booking systems work. A room_period is a single-use resource. You need to capture that in your model.